# WCF Routing Service to bridge two domains

Tags: .net, wcf, soa, wcf-routing

In my enterprise there are two domains A and B.  An application in domain A needs to call several services(WCF, Java Soap Services) belonging to Domain B. Domain B relies on Kerberos and Siteminder authentication to authenticate its client. Domain A mostly uses mutual SSL authentication.

This new routing service will support all underlying services in domain B and broker the authentication.It will authenticate Domain A caller application using mutual SSL and forward its request to appropriate endpoint.

How can I leverage WCF routing feature to bridge this gap between two domains?